# Run moving average on times series across in intervals of 5 looping through to the last column

Tags: excel, vba, average, trading

'Ideally I want to loop through to the last column on the output range below (`E6`) and then run the moving average across 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 to 50 intervals for the moving average period...

Essentially I want to tidy up the code here. I'm not a professional coder. Would appreciate some advices.

Column `C` is the price data 
`E6` is where i want it to fill across from to the last moving average i.e. 50

Sheet name is "Data"

```
Sub Mov_Avgs()

'last row
Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Moveavg", ActiveSheet.Range("$C$6:$C" & Lastrow), _
        ActiveSheet.Range("E6"), 5, False, False, False

Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Moveavg", ActiveSheet.Range("$C$6:$C" & Lastrow), _
        ActiveSheet.Range("F6"), 10, False, False, False

Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Moveavg", ActiveSheet.Range("$C$6:$C" & Lastrow), _
        ActiveSheet.Range("G6"), 15, False, False, False

Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Moveavg", ActiveSheet.Range("$C$6:$C" & Lastrow), _
        ActiveSheet.Range("H6"), 20, False, False, False

Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Moveavg", ActiveSheet.Range("$C$6:$C" & Lastrow), _
        ActiveSheet.Range("I6"), 25, False, False, False

Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Moveavg", ActiveSheet.Range("$C$6:$C" & Lastrow), _
        ActiveSheet.Range("J6"), 30, False, False, False

Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Moveavg", ActiveSheet.Range("$C$6:$C" & Lastrow), _
        ActiveSheet.Range("K6"), 35, False, False, False

Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Moveavg", ActiveSheet.Range("$C$6:$C" & Lastrow), _
        ActiveSheet.Range("L6"), 40, False, False, False

Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Moveavg", ActiveSheet.Range("$C$6:$C" & Lastrow), _
        ActiveSheet.Range("M6"), 45, False, False, False

Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Moveavg", ActiveSheet.Range("$C$6:$C" & Lastrow), _
        ActiveSheet.Range("N6"), 50, False, False, False


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using loop:

```
Sub Mov_Avgs()

Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim ColNum As Long
Dim Step As Long

Lastrow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Step = 5

For ColNum = 5 To 14
    Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Moveavg", ActiveSheet.Range("$C$6:$C" & Lastrow), _
    ActiveSheet.Cells(6, ColNum), Step, False, False, False
    Step = Step + 5
Next
```

Hope this helps!